# Mongo go driver transaction implementation with retries

Tags: mongodb, go, transactions, mongo-go

Am trying to build transaction in mongodb with retries functionality as similar to other drivers like nodejs etc. This is my current implementation

```
      if session, err = client.StartSession(); err != nil {
        return err
      }
      if err = session.StartTransaction(); err != nil {
        return err
      }
      if err = mongo.WithSession(ctx, session, func(sc mongo.SessionContext) error {
      if result, err = collection.UpdateOne(sc, bson.M{"_id": id}, update); err != nil {
        _ =  session.AbortTransaction(sc)
        return err
      }
      if result.MatchedCount != 1 || result.ModifiedCount != 1 {
        _ =  session.AbortTransaction(sc)
        return error.New("no match")
      }


      if err = session.CommitTransaction(sc); err != nil {
        _ =  session.AbortTransaction(sc)
      }
      return nil
    }); err != nil {
      // what needs to be handled here?
      // If its a particular error type can i retry transaction here?
      // should i abort transaction here?
      return err
    }
    session.EndSession(ctx)
```

If its a particular error type how can i go about retry a transaction?

Also do we need to abort transaction everytime a commit fails or returning an error will automatically cancels the transaction?

I am not able to find much examples on how to implement this right

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I could put up an example similar to other mongo drivers.

```
func trans() error {
        transactionCodeFunc := func(sctx mongo.SessionContext) error {

            err := sctx.StartTransaction(options.Transaction().
                SetReadConcern(readconcern.Snapshot()).
                SetWriteConcern(writeconcern.New(writeconcern.WMajority())),
            )
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            // Transaction - Attempt an stripe charge
            err = empService.Update(sctx, filter, update)
            if err != nil {
                sctx.AbortTransaction(sctx)
                return err
            }
            // Transaction - Attempt an stripe charge
            err = empService.Update(sctx, filter2, update2)
            if err != nil {
                sctx.AbortTransaction(sctx)
                return err
            }
            return commitWithRetry(sctx)
    }
        return db.Client().UseSessionWithOptions(
            ctx, options.Session().SetDefaultReadPreference(readpref.Primary()),
            func(sctx mongo.SessionContext) error {
                return runTransactionWithRetry(sctx, transactionCodeFunc)
            },
        )
}

    func runTransactionWithRetry(sctx mongo.SessionContext, txnFn 
      func(mongo.SessionContext) error) error {
        for {
            err := txnFn(sctx) // Performs transaction.
            if err == nil {
                return nil
            }

            log.Println("Transaction aborted. Caught exception during transaction.")

            // If transient error, retry the whole transaction
            if cmdErr, ok := err.(mongo.CommandError); ok && cmdErr.HasErrorLabel("TransientTransactionError") {
                log.Println("TransientTransactionError, retrying transaction...")
                continue
            }
            return err
        }
    }

    func commitWithRetry(sctx mongo.SessionContext) error {
        for {
            err := sctx.CommitTransaction(sctx)
            switch e := err.(type) {
            case nil:
                fmt.Println("Transaction comitted")
                return nil
            case mongo.CommandError:
                if e.HasErrorLabel("UnknownTransactionCommitResult") {
                    log.Println("UnknownTransactionCommitResult, retrying commit operation")
                    continue
                }
                log.Println("Error during commit...")
                return e
            default:
                log.Println("Error during commit...")
                return e
            }
        }
    }
```